# Web Publish Activity window is not maintained when closing and reopening Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently applied an update to Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit).
Current Version is 17.3.4

We still use Web Deploy for some legacy asp.net sites and the Web Publish Activity window is very useful for switching between dev and production environments.

After a recent Visual Studio upgrade I noticed that the Web Publish Activity window was not visible, so I reopened it via View -> Other Windows... and it appeared as expected in the lower window, as a new tab along with Output and Error List.

But after closing my project and reopening it, the Web Publish Activity window is missing again. I tested other windows like PowerShell and Bookmark Window and they ARE maintained after closing and reopening VS.

I also tried saving a new window layout with the Web Publish Activity window open and then reapplying that layout after a VS restart but that had no affect.

It is very annoying to have to go though multiple levels of the View menu to reopen this window every time I open this project.

Does anyone have any advice on how to keep this window locked/pinned?
Is Microsoft trying to "encourage" me to stop using this window?
If there is another way to quickly change between publish profiles that would be acceptable as well, but I cannot find one.

Thank you.

Comment: Apparently this is intentional behavior because they are planning on getting rid of the Web Publish Activity window: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Web-Publishing-Activity-is-no-longer-sti/10209530#T-N10214894
They mention a "tool window" for triggering the publish operation, but I can't figure out what that refers to.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug with this particular window (the fact that it doesn't stay pinned after closing Visual Studio that is).

Perhaps as a decent workaround you can at least assign a keyboard shortcut to open this window:

1. Go to Options → Environment → Keyboard
2. Filter down to "View.WebPublishAcitvity" or find it in the list
3. Create a keyboard shortcut of your liking by typing it in the circled red box and then click the Assign button:

[image: keyboard shortcut]

After doing that, you should be able to use that shortcut to open the window much faster at least.

Comment: Thanks Timothy, I would obviously prefer if the window just stayed open/pinned, but this helps. I'd also like to know if there is some other way to change the active publish profile than via the Web Publish Activity window.

Comment: @EddieB have you also tried right clicking on the project in solution explorer and selecting "Publish..." ? I wonder if that might suite you better - it will look something like this I believe https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JQoL.png (at least for .NET projects). It looks like Visual Studio opens this as a tab in the editor, which you should also be able to pin, albeit as a tab instead of a window.  This tab should allow you to switch between profiles easily too.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for our environment. Occasionally we publish individual files, by right-clicking the file and selecting publish. This just publishes the file to whatever publish profile is active and the output is displayed in the Output window. There is still no way to change between publish profiles.